# Deleting corresponding element pointed to by each element of an array of pointer in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, delete-operator

Consider that I have an array of pointers declared as:

```
MyObject** myArr = new MyObject*[someSize] ;
```

And then I assign some objects by

```
myArr[i] = myObjectInstance
```

Now, I want to delete every element pointed to by each pointer of this array. So what is the correct way to do that?
I don't think `delete[] myArr` works.

Comment: <Obligatory recommendation to not perform this kind of manual memory management and instead of use containers and memory management tools provided by the standard library>

Comment: `std::vector< std::unique_ptr< MyObject > > myArr;` and take it from there...

Comment: The correct way is to use a vector of `unique_ptr<MyObject>`'s instead of trying to manage memory manually.

Comment: I know that is recommended. I can not use a vector, and can only use arrays, and heap memory moreover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete each object first, then the whole array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < someSize; i++)
{
    delete myArr[i];
}
delete[] myArr;
```

Comment: It's going to crash if `MyObject m; myArr[0] = &m;`

Comment: The OP asked "I want to delete every element pointed to by each pointer of this array.". This is what the code above does. I trust the OP to put dyunamically allocated object in the list.

Comment: Is nice to point this case, he can be confused. (It wasn't me who downvoted)

Comment: @Jeffrey Your trust won't be broken

Comment: What if all elements are not dynamically allocated?

Comment: It would be a very bad idea to store in the same array both pointers to dynamically allocated element and non-dynamically allocated ones. If you have both, have two arrays, with meaningful names, and delete elements from the right one only.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < someSize; ++i)
    delete myArr[i];
```

That could do the trick. However you go about it, you will have to visit each element and delete it individually, and then delete the array with `delete [] myArr;`.

But dynamically allocating arrays can be messy business. In keeping up with SO traditions, I'm going to recommend `std::vector` (or whatever STL container makes sense) if you are able to use it. You would still have to individually delete all elements, but now you don't have to worry about the array itself.

As mentioned in the comments to your question, if you use smart pointers to each element, then you don't have to manually delete anything.

Comment: This is corrrect, assuming `myObjectInstance` was a pointer to `MyObject` created with `new`. There's no need for the additional indirection of the reference though. `auto i` would be sufficient.

Comment: How does this even compile ? myArr has unknown size. I get the expected:  error C2672:  'begin': no matching overloaded function found

Comment: @sweenish you cannot use range based for loop on simple array

Comment: @Kapli You can. The error is that you cannot use it on a dynamically allocated array. Had it been on the stack, a range-based for loop would work just fine. I'll edit. That was an oversight.

Comment: @Jeffrey My oversight was that it is a dynamically allocated array. If it was on the stack, range-based for loops work just fine.

Comment: @eerorika Since provided copy is still a pointer to the same dynamic resource, true. I'm just in the habit of adding the reference when making direct changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard algorithm `std::for_each` and the function object `std::default_delete`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

struct A
{
    static size_t i;
    A() { i++; }
    ~A() { std::cout << --i << ": ~A()\n"; }
};

size_t A::i = 0;

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;

    A **p = new A *[N];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        p[i] = new A();
    }

    std::for_each( p, p + N, std::default_delete<A>() );

    delete []p;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
9: ~A()
8: ~A()
7: ~A()
6: ~A()
5: ~A()
4: ~A()
3: ~A()
2: ~A()
1: ~A()
0: ~A()
```

If you want to delete the elements of the array in the reverse order relative to the order of creating them then you can write

```
std::for_each( std::reverse_iterator<A **>( p + N ), 
               std::reverse_iterator<A **>( p ), std::default_delete<A>() );
```

Comment: Up-voted, because it's very modern C++-ish. But I find for_each and default_delete to be a bit advanced, when a simple `for` could do. Depends on style, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Acctualy, `delete[] myArr` is right, because `myArr` is dynamically allocated object.

You might need to deallocate some `myArr[i]` before if you do any `myArr[i] = myObjectInstance` where `myObjectInstance` is dynamically allocated, example:

```
myArr[i] = new MyObject;
```

`delete myArr[i];` is going to crash if:

```
MyObject m;
myArr[i] = &m;
```

In the case of all positions being dynamically allocated, you can use a `for` to free memory:

```
for (int i = 0; i < someSize; ++i)
    delete myArr[i];
```

Comment: That leaks memory for the objects themselves

Comment: it depends on how they are allocated.

Comment: The OP explicitly wants to `delete every element pointed to by each pointer of this array`.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that all the `myObjectInstance` are pointers to heap allocated objects (if not so, see @JoãoPaulo 's answer), and no custom `new` or `delete` is involved.

```cpp
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < someSize; ++idx)
    delete myArr[idx];
delete[] myArr;
```

What is the potential pitfall?

Well, there are many. What if only some of the array elements are initialized? The other would be in an indetermined state, and deleting them leads to undefined behavior.

Also, what if multiple array elements points to the same object? Then you are trying to delete an object multiple times. That also leads to undefined behavior.

This doesn't mean you cannot use this naive method, it just reminds you of some pre-conditions:

1. Make sure every element of array is initialized to either "pointer to some heap allocated object" or `nullptr` (deleting `nullptr` is safe).
2. Make sure you don't delete an object twice.